# Using rbenv with the fish shell

Tags: fish

When using the recommanded way to setup rbenv, `eval "$(rbenv init -)", I get:

```
$(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(rbenv)'.
~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 5): eval "$(rbenv init -)"
                                           ^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
    called during startup
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` you can add:

```
. (rbenv init - | source)
```

It requires the latest version of rbenv: `brew install rbenv --HEAD`.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked adding these lines to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
set -x PATH $PATH <path/to/rbenv/bin>
rbenv init - | source
```

Using the latest version of rbenv.